# Google Maps: Traffic on top of Custom Map

Tags: google-maps

I want to add traffic information to my custom map. Currently I'm using a Tile Layer Overlay on my Google Map to display custom map tiles. When I try to add GTrafficOverlay to my map, my custom map tiles display above the traffic information. Is there any way to display the traffic above my GTileLayerOverlay?

(Using the JavaScript api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this in V3. Take a look at this sample: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/overlays.html#ImageMapTypes

Comment: +1 Awesome. It is about time I got into the v3 stuff. I have been putting it off ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to start using the v3 API.

Answer (score 1):

I [tried this out](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo9) and wasn't able to find a solution to the problem. There is nothing in the *GTrafficOverlayOptions* and I couldn't find anything in the references about the z-order of this stuff.  I have suspect that this isn't possible.

Would love to see an alternative answer showing that I am wrong.